# Creating a winform user control with no designer

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I create a WinForms User Control that has no GUI or designer attachment? An example is like the Timer Control, which you drop onto your form and it docks to the bottom but doesn't have any GUI controls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `System.ComponentModel.Component` as `base class`.

Example :

```
class Class1 : System.ComponentModel.Component
{

}
```

[image: Class1 is a component!]

Comment: This article will really help anyone.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hk12d4y.aspx

Comment: How can I read property ParentForm as with Control base class?

Comment: @Yogurtu: A `Component` has `Container` and `Site` properties, which have similar functionality to `Parent` and `ParentForm` in GUI controls.  When you drop a component onto the designer, the designer automatically generates code that sets these

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Control. This should change the icon from the normal "class" icon to a "component" icon in the solution explorer. You can see this effect if creating a class and inheriting from say TextBox or Timer